# Magento, curl_exec function not working

Tags: php, curl

I am doing instagram login in magento, My **curl_exec** is not giving me the output here. I dont know what mistake i had done.

My code:

```
     private function _makeOAuthCall($apiData) {
$apiHost = self::API_OAUTH_TOKEN_URL;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiHost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($apiData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 echo "<pre>";
echo "get test::::";
print_r($ch);
$jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
echo "      gggg    ";
print_r($jsonData); die;
curl_close($ch);
return json_decode($jsonData);
```

}

Before **curl_exe** function, I am getting `$ch` value as **Resource id #814**, but the `curl_exec()` functions `$jsondata` variable return empty result.

Can anyone help me to fix this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is this question tagged magento?

Comment: and if you put $apiHost directly in your web browser ? what do you get ?

Comment: I am using this functionality in magento for instagram login..I referred the following link http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/login-with-instagram-php.html